# Flooring Repairs

Tags: flooring

I have a master bedroom that was created out of two smaller rooms. The middle wall is gone so now there is a gap where the two hardwood floors end. My question is how would I fill this gap between the two floors? It is approx. 3-4 " in width.

Comment: Do both wood floors “run” parallel to wall that was removed?

Comment: you pull boards from a less-prominent spot on the floor, like a corner, and feather them in with the squared-off hole.

Comment: A picture of your floor would be really helpful.